# Stalker thriller movie from 80s

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller

Hi I'm trying to trace a film from the 1980s.

A woman is being stalked by someone. Phone calls etc. I'm almost sure he's a murderer and is taking out her close friends and family one by one.
During the film she has a friend who tries to help her etc when she's by herself etc.

The ending is that the stalker finally reveals himself and it turns out to be the guy helping her ( I know it sounds like every thriller made in the 1980s with that "twist").

A note to add is that the friend is a clean shaven well presented chap. But on the revealing of the twist he ends up with dodgy face stubble and has a limp.
In fact the limp might be something he had been concealing from her.

Comment: Sounds similar to what happens in "There's Something About Marry"

Comment: This is no comedy chap.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't gotten 2 films mixed up in your head? The plot and ending sound like 'Scream' (although this was released in 1996) but the thing about the limp sounds like a reverse of 'The Usual Suspects'. Why I think there may be a  confusion is because of the spoof 'Scary Movie', the plot is basically the same as Scream but then at the end the kill turns out to be the police officer who is helping catch the killer and at the end he stops limping. Could this be the case?

Comment: Nope. It's a film from the 80s matey.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I was unsure. The only bit that confuses me is the limp. Surely it would be the other way around? How can someone have a limp but then hide it, surely if they could do this they just wouldn't limp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Hotline (1982) - Promo Ad]

[**Hotline**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084095/) (1982)

> **Struggling artist Brianne O'Neil** is talked into being a volunteer to answer phones part-time at a crisis center. She soon finds herself
>   being **stalked by a psychotic caller**.

Here's a shot of 'nice guy' Kyle (Monte Markham):

[image: Hotline (1982) - Pic 01]

And this is him in 'stalker mode':

[image: Hotline (1982) - Pic 02]

Read more about the movie [here](http://www.hysteria-lives.co.uk/hysterialives/Hysteria/hotline.htm), [here](http://anchorwomaninperil.blogspot.com/2008/02/hotline.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotline_%28film%29). The trailer's available [here](http://www.videodetective.com/movies/hotline/2051).

The movie's been uploaded on YouTube. Watch that scene you described [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ_WhITOPjM&t=87m50s).

P.S. Couldn't resist putting up that old ad. Besides, there weren't any decent posters anywhere.

<sup>*~ Synopsis edited from [TCM](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/415898/Hotline/); Magazine clipping from [2 Warps to Neptune](http://2warpstoneptune.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/tv-guide-ads-for-tv-movies-1980-1982/); Screenshots taken directly from video*</sup>

Comment: Rumandwrite you mentalist!! How in the world did you find it chap? EXCELLENT work my friend. Superb!

Comment: Happy to help! And hope you had fun watching it after so many years :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, some things don't match, but I'll still try with [*Blue Steel*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099160/):

> On her first day on the job, NYPD officer Megan Turner, the lone
>   officer on the scene, shoots and kills the perpetrator of a
>   supermarket hold-up. Since no gun was found on the perpetrator's
>   person or at the scene and none of the witnesses could corroborate
>   Megan's story definitively that the perpetrator was indeed wielding a
>   gun, she is suspended from active duty. She is quickly albeit
>   temporarily reinstated to the position of homicide detective because
>   the spent shell casing from the bullet used in a subsequent murder had
>   her name carved on it. This murder ends up being only the first in a
>   series. Working on the case with fellow homicide detective Nick Mann,
>   Megan initially has no idea who in her life could be the murderer. In
>   short order, the murderer does show himself to her. He is commodities
>   trader Eugene Hunt who she met immediately following her suspension
>   and who she has since dated. He also implies to her that he was in the
>   supermarket at the time of the hold-up and that he ...

Here she is a cop (which you didn't mention, though) accidentally killing someone. But she is stalked on the phone by a guy that saw this and goes on his own killing spree. And it is later revealed (to her, we know all the time, I think) that he is the guy she was dating and after that he one time also appears at her family's house playing her "friend", while only she knows how dangerous he is.

But some points don't match. He doesn't have a limp and, being *Ron Silver*, he always wears a beard (though still well-presented). But maybe you have mixed him up with her partner, who is clean-shaven (and with whom she starts an affair at the end, too, I think).

Comment: Thanks for the effort my friend but it's not it. I do however have blue steel in my 80s collection ;-)

Comment: The film I'm trying to find has a twist ending where the killer reveals himself to the woman right at the end in possibly her apartment. Pretty gritty movie.

Answer (score -1):

I´m searching for the same movie, I think...is it this one:

"Someone´s watching me!" http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078295/

i hope it´s!!!